# iOS 8 and Xcode 6 Push Notification

Tags: objective-c

I am really new to iOS development and was trying to implement a simple push notification app for iOS 8 using Xcode 6. I have all the required certificates from the apple developer website along with the provision profile tied to my app id. following is the code i am implementing in app delegate.m (The code is borrowed from the web)

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    //-- Set Notification
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        // iOS 8 Notifications
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS < 8 Notifications
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }

    //--- your custom code
    NSLog(@"Registering for push notifications...");

    return YES;
}




    - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"Registering for push notifications...II"); //to see if this code gets executed...it doesnt, why?
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}

    - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```

I am running it on a physical iPhone, the problem is I cannot seem to get the device token in the nslog. I have even tried to put a simple nslog test out put under the device token code, but it seem it never gets that far. If someone could please point out what the issue is, it would most helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: Did you get log on didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError method?

Comment: Is the provisioning profile you are using enabled for remote notifications?

Answer (score 0):

gokhangultekin, Cornelius,

Thank You for your replies, I feel really silly typing the resolution to my issue, it was just that my iPhone was not connected to the internet, for some reason I just assumed that there was a tethered connection through my laptop because of the usb connection.

Thank you both for your time.
Hamood